# Cloning laptop HDD to SSD using old HDD external closure

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I have an old 3.5" external closure which I used to copy some files from a HDD out of a bust computer. Can it be used to clone my laptop's 750GB 2.5" HDD to a 2.5" SSD namely the crucial mx100 256GB. I am also worried about the external power source could it damage my SSD?

It says on the box it supports SATA 1 and 2 with further pictures detailing specs and the connections.
The PSU says input 100-240V ~ 50/60Hz 1.0A output 12.0v - 2000mA 5.0V - 2000mA

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Why wouldn't it be supported?  Its below 1.5Gb SATA is a backwards capability specification.

Comment: I am aware that it will be backwards compatible, but I am no hardware genius so I'm being precautious as I don't want £80 going down the drain by damaging the ssd. Also whether the power is compatible.

Comment: Everything I know is based on research; don't worry about the power supply if not came with the adapter